# 401 Unauthorized Request Discord API with OAuth

Tags: node.js, express, discord, passport.js

I'm wanting to allow users of my site that use [Discord](https://discord.com/) to be able to "automatically" join my `guild`.

I have everything done except I always get a `401: Unauthorized` from `Discord's API` using the following;

```js
router.get("/cb", passport.authenticate("discord", { failureRedirect: "/" }), async function(req, res) {
    const data = { access_token: req.user.accessToken };
    axios.put(`https://discordapp.com/api/v8/guilds/${config.CyberCDN.server_id}/members/${req.user.id}`, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bot ${config.CyberCDN.bot_token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then((success) => {
        console.log(`[DASHBOARD] ${req.user.username}#${req.user.discriminator} - Logging in...`);
        console.log(success.config.data)
        console.log(success.response.status)
        return res.status(200).redirect("/");
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(`[DASHBOARD] ${req.user.username}#${req.user.discriminator} - Failed Logging in...`);
        console.log(error.config.data.replace(config.CyberCDN.bot_token,"TOKEN"))
        console.log(error.response.status)
        return res.status(403).redirect("/");
    });
});
```

I don't understand how when everything I have done is correct;

I have even asked in the `Discord-API` server regarding this matter with the same issue,

I did however have it working `ONE TIME` and now it's broke again, I have 0 clue how it broke.

My scopes are as follow `"oauth_scopes": ["guilds.join"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution to this problem I had:

```js
const DiscordOauth2 = require("discord-oauth2");
const discord = new DiscordOauth2();

/** 
 * Other required stuff for express.js goes here...
 */

router.get("/login", passport.authenticate("discord"));

router.get("/cb", passport.authenticate("discord", { failureRedirect: "/forbidden" }), async function(req, res) {
    req.session.user = req.user;
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.get("/support", authOnly, async function(req, res) {
     discord.addMember({
        accessToken: req.session.user.accessToken,
        botToken: config.CyberCDN.bot_token,
        guildId: config.CyberCDN.server_id,
        userId: req.session.user.id,
        roles: [config.CyberCDN.site_role]
    }).then((r) => {
        if(r) {
          let date = new Date(r.joined_at);
          res.status(200).json({ status: "Joined Server" });
          const embed = new Embed()
              .title(`New User Joined Via Site\n${r.user.username}#${r.user.discriminator}`)
              .colour(16763904)
              .thumbnail(`https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${r.user.id}/${r.user.avatar}.webp?size=128`)
              .footer(`User joined at: ${date.toLocaleDateString()}`)
              .timestamp();
          dhooker.send(embed);
          console.log(r)
        }else{
          res.status(401).json({ status: "Already In There?" });
        }
    });
});
```

Basically through browsing my initial `401: Unauthorized` error stumbled across a nice little `OAuth2` NPM For Discord called `discord-oauth2` developed by `reboxer` and numerous other people, which can be found [here](https://github.com/reboxer/discord-oauth2).

The helpful part was documented further down the `README.md` of that repo, in relation to my problem. [Relation found here](https://github.com/reboxer/discord-oauth2#addmember)

I have also contributed that they add the `removeMember` feature also.